# C library function in Postgresql

Tags: c, visual-studio, postgresql, function

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to build a postgres function and I get this message when I try to use my function:

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>       before or while processing the request.

Here is my code:

**C:**

**.c file:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

extern "C" {
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "sysmoroundtoabnt.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sysmoroundtoabnt);

Datum
sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    PG_RETURN_INT32(10);
    //PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(10);
    //...
}
```

**.h file**

```
#ifndef SYSMOROUNDTOABNT_H
#define SYSMOROUNDTOABNT_H

#include "fmgr.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) Datum sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

#endif
```

**Postgresql:**

```
create or replace function teste_victor( double precision, integer )
returns double precision
as '$libdir/sysmoroundtoabnt', 'sysmoroundtoabnt' language C;
```

**SQL Command**

```
select teste_victor(0.015, -2)
```

PS.: if i change the C code to return PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(10), i get thi error:

> invalid memory alloc request size 4294967290

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: This is C++ code. Does it work if you use plain C? Take a look at [this guide](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) and see if there's anything else you're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve the problem:**

1. Remove `extern "C"` of both file;
2. Put `PGDLLEXPORT Datum sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)` on .h file;
3. Change `Double` to `Float8` and `Int` to `Int32` on .c File;

I guess the main problem was how I was expounding my function.

Answer (score 0):

The code with

```
PG_RETURN_INT32(10);
```

is bound to fail since the function is declared to return `double precision` and not `integer`. C is unforgiving about such mistakes.

I tried your function (without `__declspec(dllimport)`, since I use GNU C on Linux) using the correct

```
PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(10);
```

and it worked as expected.

So it seems like there must be a mistake in building the executable.

If you were using C and not Windows, I would recommend using the [PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html), but that is not an option with C++ or on Windows.

The problem is that you must build the function with the same `#define`s as PostgreSQL.
Looking at the [definition of `PG_RETURN_FLOAT8`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/fmgr/fmgr.c;h=51f3d1b00a2b3805472c895cc050a316796cb81d;hb=refs/heads/REL9_5_STABLE#l2192), I'd suspect that the `#define` in question is `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL`.

Are you using the same `include/pg_config.h` that was used when PostgreSQL was built?

Does it work if you add `/DUSE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` or `/UUSE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` to your build flags?

Did you use the same Visual Studio version that was used to build PostgreSQL?

Did you build with `\MD`?

Comment: Sorry for lack of details, but in Linux it's work perfectly, i just had to remove the `extern "C" {}` and `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)`  from code. My problems occurs only in windows. I'm using the same pg_config.h file, and i'll try to add `/DUSE_FLOAT8_BYVAL or /UUSE_FLOAT8_BYVAL`

Comment: I have two more ideas, I added them at the end of my answer.

Comment: If it's not the same Visual Studio version that was used to build PostgreSQL, how can i solve it? Rebuilding it ? How ? I did it only once with MinGW/MSYS, never with VS.

Comment: When I build my PostgreSQL extension for Windows, I just install the Visual Studio version that was used to build PostgreSQL. I am not certain that that is necessary, but I think it might be a problem if your executable is not linked with the same `MSVCR*.DLL` as PostgreSQL.

Comment: I built the dll with MinGw/MSYS, and i get the same error. I think there are something wrong with my Postgresql. I'll re-instal it, and come back later.